# How to convert a string to an object to execute the SQL command in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I wrote a piece of code inside Laravel that creates a query as a string. I need to add this query to the end of my Laravel command but when I add it I get the following error :

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

How do I add this string to the end of my SQL command?
My Code is:

```php
DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");//this is for fix groupby error!

$search = Sa_product::leftJoin('sa_product_filters' , 'sa_products.productid', 'sa_product_filters.productid');

$proptype = '';

foreach ($explodeprops as $word) {
    $explodedprops[$x] = explode(':', $word);
    if ($x == 0) {
        $proptype = $explodedprops[$x][0];
    }

    if ($proptype != $explodedprops[$x][0]) {
        $search.$query;
        $y = 0;
        if ($y == 0) {
            if (isset($explodedprops[$x+1][0]) && $explodedprops[$x][0] == $explodedprops[$x+1][0]) {
                $query = 'where(function ($q[$x]) { $q[$x]->where("sa_product_filters.product_props", "LIKE", "%{$word}%")->Where("sa_products.catid", "LIKE", "%,{$id},%")
                                ->where("sa_products.product_status","1")';
            } else {
                $query = 'where(function ($q[$x]) { $q[$x]->where("sa_product_filters.product_props", "LIKE", "%{$word}%")->Where("sa_products.catid", "LIKE", "%,{$id},%")
                                ->where("sa_products.product_status","1"); })';
            }
            $y++;
        } else {
            $search->orWhere('sa_product_filters.product_props', 'LIKE', "%{$word}%")->Where('sa_products.catid', 'LIKE', "%,{$id},%")
                        ->where('sa_products.product_status','1');
            $y++;
        }
    }

    if ($proptype == $explodedprops[$x][0]) {
        if ($y == 0) {
            if (isset($explodedprops[$x+1][0]) && $explodedprops[$x][0] == $explodedprops[$x+1][0]) {
                $query = 'where(function ($q[$x]) { $q[$x]->where("sa_product_filters.product_props", "LIKE", "%{$word}%")->Where("sa_products.catid", "LIKE", "%,{$id},%")
                                ->where("sa_products.product_status","1")';
            } else {
                $query = 'where(function ($q[$x]) { $q[$x]->where("sa_product_filters.product_props", "LIKE", "%{$word}%")->Where("sa_products.catid", "LIKE", "%,{$id},%")
                                ->where("sa_products.product_status","1"); })';
            }
            $y++;
        } else {
            if (isset($explodedprops[$x+1][0]) && $explodedprops[$x][0] == $explodedprops[$x+1][0]) {
                $query = $query.'->orWhere("sa_product_filters.product_props", "LIKE", "%{$word}%")->Where("sa_products.catid", "LIKE", "%,{$id},%")
                                ->where("sa_products.product_status","1")';
            } else {
                $query = $query.'->orWhere("sa_product_filters.product_props", "LIKE", "%{$word}%")->Where("sa_products.catid", "LIKE", "%,{$id},%")
                                ->where("sa_products.product_status","1"); })';
            }
            $y++;
        }
        if (count($explodeprops) == 1) {
            $search.$query;
        }
    }

    $proptype = $explodedprops[$x][0];
    $x++;
}
        
$search = $search->orderBy($orderby,'DESC')->groupBy('sa_products.productid')->paginate(12);
$data['productsincat'] = $search;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Just add to the builder instance like you do in the end.

Instead of

```php
$query = 'where(function (...) { ... })';
$search.$query;
```

Just chain the methods.

```php
$search->where(function(...) { ... });
```

---

If you need some conditional expressions, you can continue using `if/else` but there's also the `when/unless` query builder methods.